# Linux Mint: Sorry, the application "Global Application Menu" has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: linux-mint, crash

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Every now and again I get the message that the "Global Application Menu" has stopped. If I'm in the middle of typing and accidentally dismimss the dialog to relaunch it then I just have to reboot or whatever.

**Where is its executable & how can I find out why it's crashing?**

I've not seen anything of interest via `journalctl -xe` or through searching so I'm at a loss.

I've only been seeing this issue since upgrading to 18.04 recently.

Comment: Unclear: Are you using Ubuntu 18.04? Or Linux Mint? They are NOT the same.

Comment: Mint is offtopic here.

Comment: @user535733 unfortunately with Mint, `lsb_release -a` IDs as Ubuntu even though they're using Mint.  Therefore they indicate they're using Linux Mint in their topic so we have to assume they are.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise it would be offtopic

Comment: And yes I'm using Mint. I'm used to Ubuntu itself and only really viewed mint as "Ubuntu without gnome".